# VSCode how to know when editor is not split?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Until now, I used `cmd+2` to split the editor on Visual Studio Code and then `cmd+1` and `cmd+2` to move between the split editors. This shortcut stopped working for some reason, and I can't set it on the keyboard shortcut menu either.
I checked with another keyboard, so this is not an hardware issue.
Anyhow, I tried to set new keybindings to split the screen and move between the editors, like this:

```
[
    {
        "key": "cmd+shift+]",
        "command": "workbench.action.navigateRight",
        "when": ""
    },
    {
        "key": "cmd+shift+]",
        "command": "workbench.action.splitEditorRight",
        "when": ""
    },
    {
        "key": "cmd+shift+[",
        "command": "workbench.action.navigateLeft",
    },
]
```

The only problem, I couldn't find what I need to write in the `when` option.
I want my shortcut to split the editor only if the editor is not split yet, and to move between the editors when it is.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: I believe `multipleEditorGroups` returns whether the editor is split.

Comment: Great! I'll add it as an answer for posterity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`multipleEditorGroups` when clause context](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#available-contexts) returns true when there's more than one editor group open.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put a "when" for neither of them. Just checked vscode defaults and they don't have any.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using it with no "when" but it didn't work.